# Any custom function for Queryappend

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Queryappend is in Coldfusion - 18 and not in Coldfusion - 16.

Can anyone suggest any custom coldfusoin function for "Queryappend"

Suppose I have 2 queries :

```
Query-1
select * from user where userid > 10 order by userid asc

Query-2
select * from user where userid < 10 order by userid desc

Query append should return folowing:

userid username 
11  AA
12  BB
13  CC
9   MM
8   NN
7   OO
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ben Nadel has already done this for you (from back in 2006!) - [ColdFusion QueryAppend( qOne, qTwo )](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/114-coldfusion-queryappend-qone-qtwo.htm). Probably more performant would be to use `UNION` directly from you initial queries of the database.

Comment: @Miguel-F,  did you notice that the two order by clauses are different?  Neither did I when I first answered the question.

Comment: No I did not notice that until you pointed it out.  Maybe a typo?  The combined results example is all ascending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and most readable solution to emulate a `queryAppend()` in earlier versions of ColdFusion is by using a query of queries (`qoq`) and then using the `union all` feature to append the resultant `qoq` by not supplying an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
<cfquery name="query1" datasource="mydatasource">
    select * from user where userid > 10 order by userid asc
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="query2" datasource="mydatasource">
    select * from user where userid < 10 order by userid desc
</cfquery>

<!--- "Union all" the 2 result sets together in a qoq and don't supply an order by clause  --->
<cfquery name="queryAppend" dbtype="query">
    select * from query1
    union all
    select * from query2
</cfquery>
```

Here's a working sample of the gist https://trycf.com/gist/484d3ab19f52d81867dacdced47fad09/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish that.

```
<cfscript>
IDList1 = '1,2,3';
IDList2 = '6,5,4';
NameList1 = 'Fred,Wilma,Pebbles';
NameList2 = 'Barney,Betty,Bam,Bam';
Flinstones = QueryNew("UserID,UserName", 'integer,varchar');
Rubbles = QueryNew("UserID,UserName", 'integer,varchar');

for (i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
QueryAddRow(Flinstones);
QuerySetCell(Flinstones, 'UserID', i);

QuerySetCell(Flinstones, 'UserName'
    , ListGetAt(NameList1, i));

QueryAddRow(Rubbles);
QuerySetCell(Rubbles, 'UserID'
    , ListGetAt(IDList2, i));

QuerySetCell(Rubbles, 'UserName'
    , ListGetAt(NameList2, i));
    
}
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="All" dbtype="query">
    select UserID, UserName
    from Flinstones
    order by UserID
</cfquery>

<cfloop query = "Rubbles">
    <cfset QueryAddRow(All)>
    <cfset QuerySetCell(All, 'UserId', UserId,
        All.recordcount)>
        <cfset QuerySetCell(All, 'UserName', UserName,
        All.recordcount)>
    
    
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#all#">
```

You can play around with it [here](https://trycf.com/gist/33bacbe7d07c06bd9d39e6e9a0604fc8/acf2016?theme=monokai).

It wouldn't be that difficult to put this logic into a function that accepts two queries and returns a third.

Comment: It thought the query of queries approach was cleaner.

Comment: It was, but it didn't provide a correct solution.  The two queries in the question had different order by clauses.